# Plot Graphs in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, graph, plot

The Java Swing GUI that I'm developing needs to plot a 2D graph based on the x and y coordinates generated in the program.

Is there a Swing component for that?

Or is there any other open source package for the purpose?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should check out [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) which has Swing support.  Here are some samples:

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html

Comment: is there a tutorial doc or something of kind for using JFreeChart?

Answer (score 17):

You should look at [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart).

Answer (score 11):

check out the feature comparison for Java report and charting libraries; http://java-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting

Answer (score 1):

Here is a related answer of me: I have summary of existing tools and show a alternative option to create interactive charts with Gnuplot in a JPanel

[Java 3D plot library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740830/java-3d-plot-library/6668950#6668950)

For your case (2d charts) JFreeChart is OK. But sometimes JFreeChart is overkill for simple charts.