# How do i visualize graphs in java ?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plot Graphs in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277126/plot-graphs-in-java)

I was trying to create graphs for x and y values in my java Application. Unfortunately while using the libraries in http://www.epic.noaa.gov/java/sgt/index.html, i found that most of the classes/ methods are deprecated. Kindly help me find a way out of this. Is there any alternate library that i can use to construct a graph. I have a for loop in which i generate the x and y values. Therefore, a method where i can directly feed data and then at the end of the loop create a graph would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one here, this is the link, yes this is it: http://www.jfree.org/